# Rewrite 'create' method in Django REST Framework. Set ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

all.
I have some issues with the 'create' method which i overwrite in my ModelSerializer. By the way, my models:

```
class User(AbstractEmailUser):
    target_languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language, default='en', related_name="target_language")
    biography = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True)
    objects = UserManager()
```

And my serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ['password', 'groups', 'user_permissions', 'is_superuser',
               'is_staff']
        read_only_fields = ['date_joined', 'last_login']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        target_languages = validated_data.pop('target_languages')
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for target_language in target_languages:
            user.target_languages.add(get_object_or_404(Language, iso_639_1=target_language))
        user.save()
        return user
```

The main problem is when I trying to POST to this serializer with target_languages field like `target_languages": ["en", "es"]` it doesn't set up the ManyToMany field, it's just empty.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: How does the JSON look you send? And how does the result for a GET request look like?